# rendering multiple lists to the django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a following code in views.py which returns a zipped dict of two lists to the template ex.html :

```
    list1=["['a',1,2,3]","['b',4,5,6]","['c',7,8,9]"]
    list2=["[12-09-13,pass]","[8-05-12,fail]"]
retrun render_to_response(ex.html,dict(t=zip(list1,list2)))
```

but it's not working.zip mixes both the lists.is there any solution to it, to traverse both the lists individually in template.

in template I am using the t inside for loop

```
{% for li in t %}
    {{li}}
{% endfor %}
```

java script code.....to generate the graph:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart','table']});
  function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Job-Names', 'Total', 'Pass', 'Fail'],
             {{glist|safe}}
    ]);

    var options = {
          title : 'Project Details',
          vAxis: {title: "Number of BULDS" ,ticks : [2,4,6,8,10] },
          hAxis: {title: "Job-Names" , textPosition : "out" , slantedText : "false" , textStyle : {fontSize : 9}},
          is3D: true,
          colors : ["#194D86","#33FF66", "#FF3333"],
          pointSize: 4

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: false});
 }
```

I am using the data of above two lists to generate the graph...I am sending this data in string format... when I return a single list in form dict(t=(',').join(list1)) it will generate an graph..but if I am sending two lists..nothing is happen.. or may be I not know the solution of it

Comment: Don't zip . you can traverse lists individually .

Comment: it is not possible to render more then 1 dict...

Comment: i am generating the two differnt charts(column and line) using these lists....forgot to mention...

Answer (score 1):

**To Traverse both lists individually in template** ,

```
extra_context = {}
extra_context['list1'] = ["['a',1,2,3]","['b',4,5,6]","['c',7,8,9]"]
extra_context['list2'] = ["[12-09-13,pass]","[8-05-12,fail]"]
return render_to_response(ex.html,extra_context)
```

And in your template :

```
{% for li in list1 %}
    {{li}}
{% endfor %}

{% for li in list2 %}
    {{li}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: using it i am able to access every element but when i use that logic for sending the data to google chart to generate the column chart, its not working....

Comment: use `'` . like `'{{li}}'` . Because I guess you are using javascript library . and for input data , you will need either json or string type .

Comment: i am using the data of above two lists to generate the graph...i am sending this data in string format... when i return a single list in form dict(t=(',').join(list1)) it will generate an graph..but if i am sending two lists..nothing is happen.. or may be i not know the solution of it...

Comment: yes. i get that . can u paste your javascript code in your question for generating graph ...

Comment: Where you put data coming from dictionary in javascript code ?

Comment: is it `{{glist|safe}}` ??

Comment: assume i return dict(glist=(',').join(list1)).....when i return a single list it will work......but when i try to send more then 1 list...shows error

Comment: Ahh !! see firebug . u will see some javascript error .

Answer (score 0):

You can access the different lists using the [dot operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups):

```
{% for li in t.0 %} // t.0 would be list1
{{li}}
{% endfor %}
{% for li in t.1 %} // t.1 would be list2
{{li}}
{% endfor %}
```